# Validations for Coded UI

Tags: c#, validation, coded-ui-tests

I am new to Coded UI. I want pu some kind of validations for Texbox, dropdown list,combox box and other controls.
These validaitons are of following kind.
1) Required field validation
2) Regular expression validation
3) Renge validation
4) Comparator validation
5) controls widht,height and other type of UI related validations.

How to customize these Test Methods ? Is there any good website to learn more about it.

Comment: what type of application ?

Comment: It's windows application

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of Coded UI resourses available on the web. Microsoft's Channel 9 website has several videos. Microsoft's blogs have many good articles and [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2010/02/11/content-index-for-coded-ui-test.aspx) has an index to lots of Coded UI reference material.

For your point "*5) controls widht,height and other type of UI related validations.*". Coded UI is aimed at functional testing. Coded UI tests are intended to be independent of precise screen layout so the tests can accomodate many simple changes to layout. Such layout changes might be beacuse the application code has changed or because the application adapts to different window sizes. Coded UI is not so good at checking whether the user interface has the desired layout or whether the asthetics are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Generally to test these kind of validations which are based on User Inputs we use [parameterization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624082.aspx) of test input data and pass or fail the test case on the basis of output i.e using [assertions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286671%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

For client Side Validations you can take help of [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ab852472-abe8-4e7b-9520-d729380a9e80/client-side-validations-not-working-in-coded-ui?forum=vsautotest)

I agree that you will need some knowledge of C# if do not have already.

And for your point about UI related validations ["5) controls widht,height and other type of UI related validations."] you can opt for the frameworks which are specially meant for it like [Galen Framework](http://galenframework.com/) Since, Coded UI allows you to insert your own code snippet you can control execution of [Galen Framework](http://galenframework.com/) in the coded UI tests itself. In your case where when its a windows application galen framework may not be of any help.

Here is another tool I found that can test Layout of windows application http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/289028/White-An-UI-Automation-tool-for-windows-applicatio
I will not vouch for the success and use of [White](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/289028/White-An-UI-Automation-tool-for-windows-applicatio) as I have just read about it and never used.